# Rails - Postgres Database Not Updating New Column with Migrations (Rails 5)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, migration, ruby-on-rails-5

**Rails 5.0.0.1** I have done a million migrations thus far on this rails app and had no issues. All the sudden, with the last 2, they aren't updating the database and I can't figure out why. Everything seems to be saying it IS updating the database--the migrations seem to run and I don't get any error messages.

Here's the first one:

(20170517040333_add_shiptime_to_supplier_specifics)

```
class AddShiptimeToSupplierSpecifics < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column :supplier_specifics, :shiptime, :string
  end
end
```

My Supplier Specific model (supplier_specific.rb):

```
class SupplierSpecific < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :images, dependent: :destroy
    belongs_to :supplier
    belongs_to :item

end
```

After `bundle exec rake:db drop`, `bundle exec rake:db create`, and `bundle exec rake:db migrate`, I eventually get this output:

```
== 20170517040333 AddShiptimeToSupplierSpecifics: migrating ===================
-- add_column(:supplier_specifics, :shiptime, :string)
   -> 0.0581s
== 20170517040333 AddShiptimeToSupplierSpecifics: migrated (0.0587s) ==========
```

My Schema.rb shows:

```
create_table "supplier_specifics", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.money    "price",                scale: 2
    t.integer  "quantity"
    t.money    "shipping_cost",        scale: 2
    t.string   "link"
    t.string   "status"
    t.integer  "item_id"
    t.integer  "supplier_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",                     null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                     null: false
    t.money    "priceUpdateIndicator", scale: 2
    t.integer  "inStock"
    t.string   "shiptime"
    t.index ["item_id"], name: "index_supplier_specifics_on_item_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["supplier_id"], name: "index_supplier_specifics_on_supplier_id", using: :btree
  end
```

I even whitelisted the item (not that it should matter, right?):

```
# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def supplier_specific_params
  params.require(:supplier_specific).permit(:price, :quantity, :shipping_cost, :shiptime, :link, :status, :inStock)
end
```

Now I go into Postgres (`psql`, with the absolutely-correct database) and describe the supplier_specifics table:

```
Table "public.supplier_specifics"
Column | Type | Modifiers | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
----------------------------------------+----------+--------------+--------
 id  | integer   | not null default nextval('supplier_specifics_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |  | 
 price | money | | plain    |  | 
 quantity  | integer  | | plain    |  | 
 shipping_cost   | money  | | plain    |  | 
 link  | character varying  | | extended |  | 
 status  | character varying  | | extended |  | 
 created_at  | timestamp without time zone | not null  | plain    |  | 
 updated_at  | timestamp without time zone | not null | plain    |  | 
 item_id | integer  | | plain    |  | 
 supplier_id  | integer  | | plain    |  | 
 priceUpdateIndicator | money  |  | plain    |   | 
 inStock  | integer  |   | plain    |   | 
Indexes:
    "supplier_specifics_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_supplier_specifics_on_item_id" btree (item_id)
    "index_supplier_specifics_on_supplier_id" btree (supplier_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk_rails_2f4080469a" FOREIGN KEY (supplier_id) REFERENCES suppliers(id)
    "fk_rails_6a06cdf3af" FOREIGN KEY (item_id) REFERENCES items(id)
Has OIDs: no
```

As you can see, no new column in the database.

If theres anything I need to provide for this to make sense to someone, just let me know. Thanks, world.

Comment: I don't think this is a reason but make sure you are testing it in correct database

Comment: or you can log into db using `rails db` that will take you to proper db specified in database.yml

Comment: Also, can you check for the same in rails console

Comment: Wow, I used rails db, and figured out that even though it's a mirror of the database I was logging into with the 'psql' command, it WASN'T the same one! The old one was 'psql (9.3.11, server 9.3.14)' and the rails db one is psql (9.3.11, server 9.4.10), so I guess I'm using an entirely different instance of postgres? Is that what's going on here? At least I know I can use it now! Thanks so much! If you want to put your answer to this in a response, I can accept it as the answer.